# Progressbar not showing inside toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-progressbar, android-appbarlayout, layout-gravity

I want to show progressbar that contain inside toolbar. But it's not visible when I added layout_gravity="bottom", I want progressbar bottom of toolbar, just like browsers. 
Is there any way to achieve this? What about Appbarlayout??

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:progress="50"
        /> </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you mean like this  [link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-FdsPeJHMH0M/WUjwAwQppPI/AAAAAAAAVWg/peGwljpdLw8i2xMTHJywqKYeukf8e6fOQCLcBGAs/s1600/ToolBar_progressBarStyle.png),[link](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ye7yLmdrBpo/WUjw3PfMeVI/AAAAAAAAVWo/WwDM6YsbIXY7-td230oxjUgkbBajq52awCLcBGAs/s1600/ToolBar_progressBarStyleHorizontal.png)

Comment: i want just like  second link

Answer (score 0):

add this in yourstyles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

make an xml file like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.blogspot.android_er.toolbarprogressbar.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/toolbar" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvTitle;
ProgressBar myProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    myProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "ProgressBar start running",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tvTitle.setClickable(false);
            MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();
            myAsyncTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            publishProgress(i);
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        myProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvTitle.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

}

In this demo the progress dialog will show when you clcik the text"Hello world"

Here is the [link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2017/06/add-progressbar-in-toolbar.html) of the source

Comment: Is this not inside toolbar??